# Email in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, email

I'm pretty noob in Codeigniter and PHP and is currently learning by making projects and such for school stuff. In my project, email is included. I wanted to know what are the things I should learn in emailing and where to start. What i know is I have to configure it first in codeigniter, I guess sending is easy because there are lots of sources on how to do it. What about receiving? Do i need a third party such as "gmail smpt" for me to do it? Do i need an online server? or can I do it locally? I did google about this "email" thing but there are so many ways to do it and its confusing me. Someone who can explain it to me slowly would be better and provide sources such as step by step tutorials to do email through sending and receiving. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Email is perilous.  I would recommend using [PHPMailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/) rather than attempting anything with PHP's built-in `mail()` function. Chances are you will _not_ be able to send mail directly from your local machine unless you have a strong understanding of systems administration. Instead, you would send _through_ a 3rd party SMTP service (like Gmail, Hotmail, etc) using account credentials.  PHPMailer is configurable for that purpose.

Comment: Crafting a message which won't end up in spam folders is another difficult matter. If you work with a web host, your host may already have mailing configured such that you can send out directly from the host (rather than Gmail) and hopefully has configured DNS so that mailing works reliably. Unfortunately though, you can _never_ really control what receiving servers do with your emails.

Comment: By "receiving" above, do you mean that you want your PHP application to accept inbound mail? That is most easily done by having it sent to a 3rd party like Gmail, then using a PHP or IMAP connection in PHP to retrieve the messages. http://php.net/manual/en/book.imap.php

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski yup, accepting inbound mail.

Comment: Then receiving it with a 3rd party mailbox and pulling it out with IMAP or POP is the way to go. It is possible if you full control over the server and its local SMTP service (sendmail, postfix, exim, etc) to preempt mail to an address and pipe it to PHP then parse it out with [PEAR Mail_Mime](http://pear.php.net/package/Mail_Mime) but again, this requires significant sysadmin work alongside the code. Way easier to use a 3rd party inbox.  (the 3rd party may be your hosting service's IMAP inbox too, need not be something like Gmail)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Codeigniter has pretty good email system on it. You can learn so much by looking on user guide pretty easy to understand.

You can find out more by reading through the user guide http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/

Good tutorial how to set up email codeigniter https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VlNz6GlSjPo

Email Class http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/email.html

```
$this->load->library('email');

$config['protocol'] = 'sendmail';
$config['mailpath'] = '/usr/sbin/sendmail';
$config['charset'] = 'iso-8859-1';
$config['wordwrap'] = TRUE;

$this->email->initialize($config);

$this->email->from('your@example.com', 'Your Name');
$this->email->to('someone@example.com');
$this->email->cc('another@another-example.com');
$this->email->bcc('them@their-example.com');

$this->email->subject('Email Test');
$this->email->message('Testing the email class.');

$this->email->send();

echo $this->email->print_debugger();
```